# nginx proxy_cache_background_update after cache expiry

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to configure nginx to use proxy_cache_background_update but it seems like after expiry it still waits for the full roundtrip to the backend, returning a MISS in X-Cache-Status. What am I MISSing?

I'm using nginx 1.11.12 under ubuntu 14.04 running inside docker, but hopefully this is too much detail.

```
location ~ ^/?(\d+/[^/]+)?/?$
{
   expires 20s;

   proxy_cache app_cache;
   proxy_cache_lock on;

   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

   proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:5000;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   error_log    /nginxerror.log debug;

   add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

   proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
   proxy_cache_background_update on;

   break;
}
```

Comment: for anyone looking for an answer to this I've asked the same question at the nginx forum here: https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,273417,273417#msg-273417. It really boils down to wrong cache-related headers (Cache-Control,Last-Modified/ETag), and basically nothing to do with nginx. I'd love to write a more detailed answer when I get some time unless someone else comes first.